# Sum of two dependent random variables

Tags: statistics, probability

I am trying to find (or at least sketch) on distribution of two exponential distributions with different parameters.

Under independence, it becomes very easy using convolution and joint distribution (which would be the multiplication of marginals).

However, if independence is not assumed, then it looks the problem is going crazy.

I've looked for many papers about it, but all I learned are asymptotics (mostly to normal distribution) or we need to know how they are related (i.e. one is function of another).

I want to know if that is really the only way to find such distribution.

Any comments or sketches are welcomed.

Thank you

Finding asymptotic distributions or papers

Comment: What do you know about dependency between those two RVs?

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. On the face of it, it seems like you might make progress by writing out the definition of the density of the sum (which is going to be a simple convolution when they're independent) and seeing what is needed to make progress. Without looking at it carefully, I will guess that maybe another integration over one variable or the other is necessary.

Comment: Another thought is to create some simulations and directly construct histograms of the sum of dependent variables for different parameters. That won't yield a general result, but you can get a feel for the problem and see how the results depend on assumptions about dependence and stuff like that.